# Submit form without refreshing page in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a listbox2 that's filled according to what has been selected in the listbox1. So when i submit the form, i lose the data of listbox2 and i have to reselect in the listbox1 again.
How can i keep data in listbox2 after submitting ?

```
<form:form action="choseElement" method="post"> 
<select name="listbox1">
 <j:forEach items="${elementList}" var="elem">
   <option>${elem.name}</option>
 </j:forEach>
</select>
</form:form>
<form:form action="addProduct" method="post"> 
 <input type="text" name="nameProd">
 <select name="listbox2">
 <j:forEach items="${LPbyElement}" var="lp">
   <option>${lp.name}</option>
 </j:forEach>
 </select>
</form:form>
```

Comment: have you tried using ajax?

Comment: Either use AJAX, or modify your server-side code to bind the two together.

Comment: I just update my question, here is the code that  i write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i submit the form, i lose the data of listbox2 and i have to
>   reselect in the listbox1 again.

you have not mentioned about how you binding your form data and passes to controller from jsp, am considering you have model bean like below:

ProductBean class to hold form data:

```
public class ProductBean {

private String listbox1Selected;
private String listbox2Selected;

  //no-arg constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Option class to load options in listbox or selectbox:

```
public class Option {    
    private String name;

    public Option(){}

    public Option(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and in jsp use like below to get selected option after form submit:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="productBean">
    <label  for="listbox1">listbox1:</label>
    <form:select path="listbox1Selected">
        <option value="NONE">--listbox1--</option>
        <form:options items="${listbox1Options}" itemValue="name" itemLabel="name"/>
    </form:select>

    <label  for="listbox2">listbox2:</label>            
    <form:select path="listbox2Selected">
        <option value="NONE">--listbox2--</option>
        <form:options items="${listbox2Options}" itemValue="name" itemLabel="name"/>
    </form:select>

    <input type="submit" />
</form:form>
```

and in controller return the product model bean what spring passed to POST parameter.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/selectBox")
public class SelectBoxController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSelectBox(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("productBean", new ProductBean());
        return "selectBox";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showSelectBox(@ModelAttribute("productBean")ProductBean productBean, BindingResult result, ModelMap model){
        System.out.println(productBean);
        model.addAttribute("productBean", productBean);
        return "selectBox";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("listbox1Options")
    public List<Option> populateOpt(){
        List<Option> lst = new ArrayList<Option>();
        lst.add(new Option("Op1"));
        lst.add(new Option("Op2"));
        lst.add(new Option("Op3"));
        return lst;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("listbox2Options")
    public List<Option> populateOpt2(){
        List<Option> lst = new ArrayList<Option>();
        lst.add(new Option("Op4"));
        lst.add(new Option("Op5"));
        lst.add(new Option("Op6"));
        return lst;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ajax to achieve this

```
    function getSubList(val){
           $.ajax({
                url: 'your-url',
                type: 'post',
                data: {param:val},
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#id-of-sublist').html(msg);
                },

            });
    }
```

Now in your first list you can call `onChange(this.value)`

**Note :**  Your server should return values in the below format

```
<option>value1</option>
<option>value2</option>
```

Comment: What is person in my case ?