# Spring MVC JSP select tag - List objects GROUP BY

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a User table based on the following attributes:

**User** (id, firstname, lastname, age).

All users were grouped by age and every age must be listed in a select tag.

Spring Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listByAge")
public String listByAge(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("ages", userService.groupByAge());
    return "/listByAge";
}
```

JSP form, select tag:

```
<form:form action="/usersByAge/${age}" method="POST">
        // The problem to list is here... 
        // I need to create a select tag
        <button type="submit">List</button> 
</form:form>
```

Somebody can help to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24390678/1066779)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose userService.groupByAge() returns a `MAP<Integer, User>` Then you can list it in jsp as following

```
<c:forEach var="age" items="${ages}">
    <option value="${age.key}">${age.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

In this way you can iterate the ages from a map.